# Mysql Regex ending with language iso code but not other chars (non alphabetical)

Tags: mysql, regex

EDITED:
i have a mysql table row with 'option_name'.

The option names are:

```
my_option_en
my_option_de

my_option_adv_en
my_option_adv_de
my_option_sc_en
my_option_sc_de
my_option_labs_en
my_option_labs_de
```

A query for the option name `my_option_` should return `my_option_en` and `my_option_de` but not any other option names

What i need is look for given string ending with 2 any letters (language iso 
 code) and no any character after the 2 language iso letters.

How can i realize it with Mysql REGEXP? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL regexp form, you would need

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE option_name REGEXP  '^my_option_[a-z]{2}$'
```

Comment: Thats it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This will discard every row where `option_name` starts with `my_option_adv`:

```
select option_name
from yourtable
where not(option_name regexp '^my_option_adv')
```

**Demo here:** [db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ho6iLarFW6YSxmJqZ6EsJR/0)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my question. I was not clear enough. Again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(option_name) = 12
```

will do exactly what you stated.  But I suspect that is not good enough.